# Weak signal even if I'm only 5 meters away from my modem

Tags: wireless, networking, signal

I'm having kind of a weak signal on Ubuntu, about 2 bars (I have a laptop), when i go on windows it really gets quicker (5 bars). What may cause this? My wifi worked as soon as I installed Ubuntu so i did not install a network driver. According to connection informations, I am using the ath9k drivers. I can provide more informations if needed. My wifi adaptor is a Atheros® WB225 (802.11b/g/n) and my bluetooth is set off. I also use a 2,4GHz wireless mouse which I have been told may cause interference? Anyway how can i fix this problem please?

Here are my [lspci](http://pastebin.com/ZATGG7RV) and [lsmod](http://pastebin.com/48um4rsV).

Answer (score 0):

Try a speedtest  (download and upload) is the speed the same? and does the signal have the same reach (distance away from modem)? I have that, the signal looks lower, but is the same speed/reach.

Comment: My speedtests are always [good](http://www.speedtest.net/result/2196698333.png) with my laptop, better than my cabled computer actually. Just wondering why i have 2 bars/5 instead of max.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316126 would this help?

Comment: Well it reccomends installing backport modules but there's a ton of them so which one do i install?

Comment: they are saying
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-karmic followed by sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-karmic-generic

I don't know if it will work, but it is worth a try

Comment: Both gives a impossible to find package error.